# In vanilla js vite project three.js model is not loading in live site

Tags: three.js, vite

My three.js model is not loading, I'm using vite as web bundler. it’s always give me all these error

> Error: THREE.GLTFLoader: Failed to load buffer “scene.bin”.
> loadBuffer
> https://timely-sunflower-f7fb45.netlify.app/assets/index-aca35cc6.js:3416
> load
> https://timely-sunflower-f7fb45.netlify.app/assets/index-aca35cc6.js:3416
> THREE.GLTFLoader: Couldn’t load texture textures/M_Monitor_normal.png
> index-bfd69eb1.js:3416:169931
>
> THREE.GLTFLoader: Couldn’t load texture
> textures/M_Speakers_baseColor.png index-bfd69eb1.js:3416:169931
>
> THREE.GLTFLoader: Couldn’t load texture textures/M_Details_normal.png

but it’s perfectly load, I mean my model perfectly load on my localhost, but when I upload my build file on vercel or netlify my `scene.gltf` and textures are not load properly and also if you stay maybe 3-5 minutes on my site then you’ll see the model. I read so many article about it, many people recommended me create a img folder in my public folder and then add "scene.gltf" and textures file in it. but it's working,
is anyone here can help me out to fix this problem

I couldn't show you the code here, that's added the github repo link and live site link.
this is my github link:GitHub - NAYMUR143/three.js
this is my project link: https://timely-sunflower-f7fb45.netlify.app/ 1

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can check the website everything is working fine. But the textures are huge like really huge (100mb+):
[image: loading time]

for a faster start i would try to reduce the file size using maybe https://squoosh.app/editor etc. i guess 2048 x 2048 should be the max res, also maybe use jpg (not on the normal channel).

For debug it is important to turn "disable chache" on so you get a feeling how long the user will wait:
[image]